# How can I calculate the impulse caused by a nuclear bomb on structures?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, momentum, nuclear-physics, estimation, explosions

I want to calculate the impulse caused by a nuclear bomb on structures. Is there a function that I can use to calculate the amount of impulse acted upon by a nuclear bomb depending on its size? Also, is there a function relating impulse to overpressure? How would I calculate overpressure? I am very new to this topic, and google hasn't been much help!

Comment: There isn't going to be a simple formula relating overpressure to impulse, because overpressure could be the same on all sides of the building, so the forces would cancel out. You're going to need to take into account the variation of the pressure with respect to time and space. This variation may be complicated -- it may be a shock wave rather than a well-behaved sine wave.

Answer (score 0):

I presume you are addressing only blast (pressure damage from the shock wave) and not thermal effects.  The blast magnitude depends on the position where the weapon is detonated: high altitude, low altitude, or on the ground. I presume you are considering low altitude air detonation.

There are detailed relationships and graphs for estimating the overpressure.  The ones I have are official use only, so unfortunately, I cannot provide them here.  I would be highly skeptical of information on the web.

Sorry I cannot provide more details here.